# TensorFlow Wide and Deep Model , how many features can I use ?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

In this wide and deep model with tensorflow https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide_and_deep, is there a limit of number of features? I mean is it possible to use 20 columns for training and prediction ?

I tried to train my model with 20 columns, and to predict, but I had this error below

> **Exception during running the graph: Unable to get element as bytes.**

I didn't really understand this error, but I think it is linked to the number of features, cause when I tried with 19 columns, prediction worked!

PS: I'm working on GCP with GCS and GCMLE
Here is the model on my github https://github.com/SofiaAmel/censusTest/blob/master/trainer/model.py

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are no limits to the number of columns. The error you are seeing probably indicates some problem specifically with the column you added.